# process launch by os.system can not recv signal SIGPIPE

Tags: python, linux

I have a server app written by C++. I found if this app launch by python code:

```
import os
os.system('./server&')
```

It can not react with signal SIGPIPE. The command

```
kill -s 13 pid
```

do nothing(the C++ server haven't omit SIGPIPE, so after the kill, the process should quit). However if I launch the server just by command:

```
./server&
```

It can react with SIGPIPE(quit)

I have test other signals, SIGKILL, SIGTERM, SIGSEGV, SIGINT can work. Only SIGPIPE can't.
Why? What python or linux do?

Linux: Ubuntu 16.04
Python: 2.7.12

Comment: Never use `os.system`, please. It creates an unnecessary shell.

Comment: Servers often deliberately ignore `SIGPIPE` because they correctly handle writing to a closed pipe.

Comment: I known that. I just curious why only SIGPIPE be ignored. If I want use python to launch a process, which api should I use?

Comment: Anything can be ignored if you set to `SIG_IGN` ... or blocked with `sigprocmask`. \n Use `subprocess.Popen` and its convenience functions.

Comment: What's the problem of an unnecessary shell? I use it for a while, seems OK?